# How we can get unique information about the iPad?

Tags: java, ios, ipad

I have a Java web application. I want to get the Ipad name or serial number or UDID or other information when the user access to my app. 
If you have any solution to this. Can you tell me how to get there?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is intentionally not possible for a web site (written in any language) to be able to get uniquely identifiable information about each visitor's hardware, so unless you can control the browser or other app that is being used (on the iPad) to make the request, there's no way to do what you want.

The only information your web server will receive about the visitor is the information they disclose in the HTTP request they make (user agent string, cookies, their IP address, etc.).